# Можно ли использовать переводчик Yandex в Python?

Tags: python, яндекс-переводчик

Хочу использовать переводчик Yandex в своём скрипте на Python. Нашёл библиотеку [deep-translator](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator), которая позволяет это делать, но похоже там проблемы с совместимостью. Захожу на cloud.yandex.ru, после продирания через длиннющую пошаговую инструкцию с непонятностями и ошибкам наконец генерирую ключ - получается два значения - id и собственно ключ. А библиотека принимает только параметр api_key, никаких id. Подставляю ключ, вызываю функцию translate - она выдаёт ошибку deep_translator.exceptions.ServerException: ERR_KEY_INVALID.
Либо библиотека перестала быть совместима с Яндекс API, либо документация что-то недоговаривает и нужно передавать ключ как-то по другому. Или нужен ключ от какого-то совсем другого API, типа yandex.com, хотя он шлёт на cloud.yandex.ru.

В общем подскажите пожалуйста, какой есть рабочий способ использовать переводчик Яндекс из Python? Может есть какие-то другие библиотеки, которые работают?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже я разобрался. В [официальной документации](https://cloud.yandex.ru/ru/docs/translate/operations/translate#python_1) есть пример кода на Python. Если использовать его то всё работает.